# C++ Modifying a vector using a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

So, I have a vector that is either full of integers. Lets call this vector `Vect`. I have my code in `main.cpp` and `VectorList.h`, and cannot change that fact. In `VectorList.h` one of my functions is:

```
void insertAtFront( const int & );
```

Now where I'm encountering trouble, I know I can add the integer to the start of the vector using `std::vector.insert()` function. But, `insertAtFront` does not have access to the vector itself, however, this is the only data member in `VectorList.h`:

```
vector< int > *vList
```

So, my question is how can I add a value to the beginning of a vector `Vect` using only this pointer `*vList`?

My first idea was something like this:

```
&vList.insert(&vList.begin(), 1, &value)    // with value being the input integer
```

but that doesn't work :/ any suggestions?

Comment: This is basic C++. I'll recommend you [a good introductory C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/46642).

Comment: Thanks, Well I am in an introductory C++ course so that might explain my shortcomings.

Comment: No need to explain yourself, everyone has to start sometime :)

Comment: May I ask why you're using a pointer to a `vector` in the first place?  That really defeats the best aspect of using a `vector`; you don't have to manually manage memory yourself, the `vector` takes care of it for you.  If you use a pointer you still have to manually `delete` it.

Comment: haha, I'll have to ask my professor why he's making us do it that way to answer you..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a pointer to a vector, then you would need to use the `->` operator. Using the `&` operator in this case will give you the address of the return value of `vList.begin()`. That won't work too well, considering you can't use the `.` operator on a pointer to begin with. Instead, you need to dereference the pointer. Try:

`vList->insert(vList->begin(), value);`

Edit: I'm not sure why you would need the middle argument in this case. You should be fine omitting it. I have done so in the line of code I wrote here.

Comment: Actually `&` has lower precedence than `.` so it will give you the address of the return value of `insert`

Comment: Good point, thanks for pointing that out. Now we're even haha.

Comment: Oh thanks for pointing that out, I have it because in other functions I insert values at various points in the vector.

Comment: @PatrickJohnston if you're only inserting one copy of `value`, you don't need the middle argument. You only ever need it if you want to insert a bunch of `value` at once (the number that you pass as the middle argument will be the number of copies that get inserted).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the pointer points to a valid `vector`, just dereference the vector and call `insert`:

```
vList->insert(vList->begin(), value);
// same thing as: (*vList).insert(vList->begin(), value);
// same thing as: (*vList).insert((*vList).begin(), value);
// same thing as: vList->insert((*vList).begin(), value);
```

Comment: You need to dereference `vList` in `vList.begin()` also.

Comment: `(&var) // get a pointer to var`, `(*var) // get what var points at`, `var.func() // call func() member of var`, `var->func() // call func on what-is-pointed-to-by-var`, `(*var).func() // equivalent to var->func()`

Comment: @rvalue: Nice explanation. I just want to point out that `(*var)` will only work if `var` is a pointer.